Controlling navigation from viewmodel
My NavHost and all of my navigation logic is in jetpack compose.
I was wondering, is there any way to navigate (using navController) to a certain page when my viewmodel initializes?
If that is not possible, are there any workarounds?

Build flow like this
This is your composable
val viewModel: AAAViewModel = viewModel()
val state by viewModel.screenState.collectAsState()

LaunchedEffect(key1 = state.isComplete) {
    if (state.isComplete) {
        //navigate to your required screen but first reset variable so when you came back it doesnt get stuck in loop
        viewModel.clearCompleteVariable()
        navController.navigate(PinScreenDestination)
    }
}

Your view model
data class AAAScreenState(
    val isComplete: Boolean = false,
)

class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val _screenState = MutableStateFlow(AAAScreenState())
    val screenState = _screenState.asStateFlow()

    fun testFunc() =
        _screenState.update { it.copy(isComplete = true) }

    fun clearCompleteVariable() =
        _screenState.update { it.copy(isComplete = false) }
}


So the only way to control navigation from the viewmodel is by using a state?

Or any other live state management system. We can use data store too but its far form optimized way
